# Can't read data using UART on esp8266 from LE-01MR electricity meter and using rs485

Tags: python, micropython

I try to read data from LE-01MR electricity meter, and according to it's documentation (https://www.fif.com.pl/en/usage-electric-power-meters/517-electricity-consumption-meter-le-01mr.html), I have to send command 0x03 to be able read data from it. Hovewer, I'm not able to do it, my result is always None, which, according to micropython documentation, tells me that I get timeouted (https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.UART.html#machine-uart). I tested if the wiring is correct with another computer connected to the wires, and I was able to read data from that, so wiring shouldn't be a problem. I connected tx/rx pins from esp8266 to tx/rx (respectively). Here is my code, any help would be appreciated:

```
import utime
from machine import UART
from machine import Pin

import uos

def test():
  print("modbus")
  uos.dupterm(None, 1)
  modbus = UART(0)
  modbus.init(9600, parity=None, stop=1, timeout=500, timeout_char=2, tx=Pin(1), rx=Pin(3))
  print("Reading from modbus: {}".format(modbus))
  print("Can read: {}".format(modbus.any()))
  while True:
    modbus.write(b'\x03')
    result = modbus.read(4)
    print("Value of reading: {}, type of {}".format(result, type(result)))
    utime.sleep(0.5)
  uart = UART(0, 115200)
  uos.dupterm(uart, 1)
```

Thank you once again!

Comment: My first impression is you are wiring directly pins from the micro board to the meter. Does your board have an RS-485 transceiver?

Comment: Sorry for late response. No, my board doesn't have it, but I wired it. Also, by using Serial monitoring program, I was able to find the request that was being sent to my meter. When I put it in my code, I get response, but it's different that what I see in that program. The request I found: 01 03 a0 00 00 02 e6 0b. The answer, that I see in program, is 01 03 04 00 00 08 c6 7d a1, but I get 01 10 00 x8 e8. Any clue of why it's happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding of the task is a bit off the mark.

Modbus is a full-blown protocol, what you need to do is send Modbus command 03 (*read holding registers*). What you are doing is just sending hex `0x03`.

You should probably start by finding a good Modbus tutorial on YouTube or Google.

After you do that you will probably realize you need a Modbus library for your microcontroller. You might want to start [here](https://github.com/techbase123/micropython-modbus). I cannot guarantee it will work with your setup but it looks promising. You can of course write your own implementation of the Modbus protocol if you feel like doing it.

If you need more details after you start playing with the library feel free to edit your question.

Good luck and have fun with your project.

Comment: Sorry for late response. By using Serial monitoring program, I was able to find the request that was being sent to my meter. When I put it in my code, I get response, but it's different that what I see in that program. The request I found: 01 03 a0 00 00 02 e6 0b. The answer, that I see in program, is 01 03 04 00 00 08 c6 7d a1, but once I send that same request with a program, I get 01 10 00 x8 e8. Any clue of why it's happening?

Comment: Dude, no offense but have you read what I wrote?